# Using if else blocks getting missing right parenthesis error

Tags: oracle, parentheses, ora-00907

I'm new to `Oracle` and having knowledge of `MS SQL`. I'm trying to get a phone number depending upon the `user_id` from `Table2` and here is the business logic:

- Case1: if a single match is found in `Table1` then get it's respective toll free number from `Table2`
- Case2: if no match is found in `Table1` then get the default toll free number from `Table2`
- Case3: if an multiple match is found in `Table1` then for all those `assigned_care_levels` get the `Care` value from `Table2` ordered by `asc` or `desc` and select the top row phone number.

I wrote the following query which works fine when I run it individually. However, when I cobine it using the if else statements I'm getting the following error `ERROR: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`. Here is my code:

```
if ((select count(distinct care_level) from Table1 where user_id = '100') > 0)
    select phone from Table2 where care_level in (select distinct care_level from Table1 where user_id = '100')
    and rownum = 1 
    order by care_level asc
else if((select count(distinct care_level) from Table1 where user_id = '100') = 0)
    select phone from Table2 where care_level = 'default'
```

Comment: Where you are trying to execute this? Is it PL/SQL stored procedure? Because there is no `IF` statement support in Oracle SQL.

Comment: No, it's not an stored proc. I was trying to execute it using Visual studio Orcale query editor.

Comment: As I mentioned above there is no `IF` statement in Oracle SQL. And I doubt that even if you replace it with `CASE` your construction will run. You would rather save `count(distinct care_level)` to some host variable and implement logic in your client application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
       v_CARE_COUNT NUMBER := 0;
       v_PHONE VARCHAr2(40) := NULL;
BEGIN
      select  count(distinct care_level) 
         into v_CARE_COUNT
      from Table1 
       where user_id = '100';

      IF(v_CARE_COUNT > 0) THEN

         select phone into v_PHONE 
         from Table2 
         where care_level in 
           (select distinct care_level from Table1 where user_id = '100')
         and rownum = 1;
      ELSE
         select phone into v_PHONE
          from Table2
         where care_level = 'default';
      END IF;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PHONE is <'||v_PHONE||'>');
 EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Exception : '||SQLERRM);
 END;
 /
```

**EDIT:** ( AS SIngle SQL)

```
 SELECT PHONE 
 FROM TABLE2
 WHERE CARE_LEVEL in
       (
          SELECT CARE_LEVEL FROM TABLE1 WHERE USER_ID='100'
           UNION
          SELECT CARE_LEVEL FROM TABLE1 WHERE CARE_LEVEL='default'
            AND NOT EXISTS
              (SELECT 'X' FROM TABLE1 WHERE USER_ID='100')
        )
 AND ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried your Orcale query but I get different error as shown below.

Comment: can you paste the error text? i dont see any thing here sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your time again Ravi. Here is the error I'm getting. "ERROR
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option"

Comment: you get this , when you run a "Single SQL" of mine?

Comment: Yes, I tried that query too but it gives the same initial error. "ERROR
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis". If I remove the following statement " AND NOT EXISTS
              (SELECT 'X' FROM TABLE1 where user = '100')" then it works fine.

Comment: No, you are missing something else. the same query runs fine for me. you append it dynamically as multiple strings ?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I just figured it out. Your second query works fine.

Comment: I missed a semicolon I the else part of PL/SQL.. I corrected it.

Comment: with PL/SQL, still the same error "ORA-00922: missing or invalid option".

Comment: how you run the plsql, you make a create or replace procedure? can u ping it shortly?

Comment: I tested out my application code and the sql code is working fine. So I'm good here, thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

The 'else if' syntax is wrong. In Oracle you need to use 'ELSIF' and complete the whole conditional statement with an 'END IF'. The SQL statements within should also be followed with a ;

Try:

```
IF ((select count(distinct care_level) from Table1 where user_id = '100') > 0) THEN
    select phone from Table2 where care_level in (select distinct care_level from Table1 where user_id = '100')
    and rownum = 1 
    order by care_level asc;
ELSIF ((select count(distinct care_level) from Table1 where user_id = '100') = 0) THEN
    select phone from Table2 where care_level = 'default'; END IF
```